# How can I open a Modal-Dialog window with scrollbars in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I need to put scrollbars on a ModalDialog window in javascript or jquery.

The window.showModalDialog() doesn't recognize scrollbars as argument [[http://javascript.gakaa.com/window-showmodaldialog-4-0-5-.aspx]](http://javascript.gakaa.com/window-showmodaldialog-4-0-5-.aspx),
while the window.open() supports it but isn't a ModalDialog
[[http://javascript.gakaa.com/window-open-4-0-5-.aspx]](http://javascript.gakaa.com/window-open-4-0-5-.aspx).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Jquery dialog like this,  [Jquery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)

Comment: @stavors, it shall automatically show the scrolls in the Div when necessary, btw its in the style of dialog.